# Regarding routing in nodejs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I had like 100 blogs on "/" page and also a link to Sortby Date:a-z When I click
these link I m transferred to different routes one is "/sort_by_date" and other is "/sort_alphabetically".I want this sorting to appear on "/".I m not able to do it on "/" page that is whay I had specified to different routes.I want this sorting to appear on "/" page by clicking to differnt links different sorting should be appear.This whole application is written in nodejs Mongoose express.

The homepage of the blog

```
 router.get('/', function (req, res) {
 var q= blog.find({}).limit(100);
 q.exec(function(err,docs)
 {
res.render('blog',{"no_of_blogs":docs
                      ,"in_ca":true })          
 });        
 });
```

The page which is sorting by date

```
  router.get('/sort_by_date', function (req, res) {
  blog.find({},{sort:{date:-1}},function (err, docs) {

    res.render('index_date_blog',{"no_of_blogs":docs
                      ,"in_ca":true })                        
   });      
 });
```

This is the page sorted by alphabetically

```
     router.get('/sort_alphabetically', function (req, res) {
          blog.find({},{sort:{title}},function (err, docs) {

            res.render('index_date_blog',{"no_of_blogs":docs
                      ,"in_ca":true })                        
            });     
            });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the query string to pass in the sort variable.
Make your links to change the sort link to `?sort=title` or `?sort=date`

Note, below code is not tested, but should help you along the way:

```
 router.get('/', function (req, res) {

 var sortQuery = req.query.sort;
 var sort = {};

 if(sortQuery=='date')
  sort={date:-1}

 if(sortQuery=='title')
  sort={title: 1}

 var q= blog.find({}).limit(100).sort(sort);

 q.exec(function(err,docs)
 {
   res.render('blog',{"no_of_blogs":docs ,"in_ca":true })          
   });        
 });
```